# Using python to access Outlook folders

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to use python to access/retrieve information from folders from Outlook. Now, I found that I can access my default inbox easily enough with something like:

```
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
```

The problem is that I need to access emails from a "Personal Folder" which I THINK is stored locally but I'm not positive. Any ideas?

Also, is there a database with some information on how to do other things with emails from Outlook? I am in way over my head, I do not come from much of a programming background so I am really stumbling through this project.

Once I am able to access my personal folders, I need to search the emails/attachments for certain keywords and grab data from those emails. Any piece of information you have that may help me is very welcome! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution to your problem but helping out others who would want to do further.

Here is a complete list of "*GetDefaultFolder*" with there codes:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861868.aspx

And here is a link to youtube video which does the same what you want:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCQOgNwXqRc